# Laravel user sessions

Tags: session, laravel

How do I distinguish between a session which stores data about a **logged-in** user, and a session which doesn't have any data about a logged-in user (basically a session which belongs to a logged-out viewer of the page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether a user is logged in via `Auth::check`

See http://laravel.com/docs/security#authenticating-users

**Update**

Here's the output of `Session::all()`. The first one is of a unauthenticated user:

```
Array (
    [flash] => Array (
    [old] => Array (
    )
    [new] => Array (
    )
)
[_token] => sqwf2m9vxjePpq0jYWw4Vs16nhXoFBGH4PT14xpm
[language] => de
)
```

And a authenticated user:

```
Array (
    [flash] => Array (
    [old] => Array (
)
[new] => Array (
)
)
[_token] => sqwf2m9vxjePpq0jYWw4Vs16nhXoFBGH4PT14xpm
[language] => de
[login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc] => 1
)
```

A look into the source tells us what's going on:

[`public function login(UserInterface $user, $remember = false)`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php#L403)

So there's a way of distinguishing a logged in user from a user "just passing by", of course..

Comment: I'm aware of this, but I is there any difference between the data in the session if a user is logged in and if a user is logged out?

Comment: In other words, are sessions authentication-blind?